# Woocommerce: где хранится количество товара?

Tags: woocommerce

Всем привет. Такая проблема. Сайт balkon. club.

Сделал специально, чтобы количество можно было ввести меньше 1.
Но при добавлении товара в корзину, если ввести количество 0.1, то товар не добавляется.
Если ввести 1.5 то добавляется товар в количестве 1.

Кто знает, где хранится количество товара? Как найти то самое местечко, где количество преобразуется в целое?

Comment: Решил проблему) нашел место)

Comment: @Evgeny777, По возможности публикуйте ответы на форуме, они могут помочь многим в будущем.

Comment: Вот то самое место)

файл wp-content/plugin/woocommerce/include/class-wc-form-handler.php
<br>
обновление корзины
public function update_cart_action() {

добавление в корзину
public function add_to_cart_action( $url = false ) {

Answer (score 1):

[@Evgeny777](/users/22541/evgeny777) запихнуть куда-нибудь пораньше

```
remove_filter( 'woocommerce_stock_amount', 'intval' );
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Вставил до расчета корзины и после расчета. Но результата нет. Может не туда вставляю?